# set progress bar value from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable which updates based on percent file downloaded. How can I get this variable to update a progress bar?

```
var percent = (len / res.headers['content-length']) * 100;
```

I have tried this to no avail:

```
<progress class="progress"></progress>

$('.progress').val = percent;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the value using the setter of `.val(newValue)`. `val` just gives you the function reference, you are just resetting it to the value of variable percent, not really assigning it as value.

Change

```
 $('.progress').val = percent;
```

to

```
 $('.progress').val(percent);
```

You could also do `$('.progress')[0].value = percent`. probably that is what you had in mind. But `val` in jquery is used as a function, (more like getter, setter kind of functionality).

Also do remember that progress element takes value ranging from `0.0` to `1.0` or the value of the max attribute (if present).

Comment: OK thanks .. the progress bar jumps to 100% almost immediately. Is there something to control this?

Comment: @Jrags87 See this example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZFcrZ/ You should make sure the values you are assinging are in the rand 0.0 to 1.0 since you dont have max attribute. otherwise set the max to 100 or whatever number you think is needed.

Comment: Got it! Thanks .. I needed to add max=100

Answer (score 1):

Pass `value` in **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val)** like,

```
$('.progress').val(percent);
```

**HTML**

```
<progress class="progress" value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnJM6/)**

Answer (score 0):

you are giving in wrong way

give like this

```
 $('.progress').val(percent);
```

see **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Your method is wrong in jquery you need to write like this:

$('.progress').val(percent);
```